# How can I remove this fastener?

Tags: screws

This is from a serving tray in bamboo, whose legs won't stay tucked in when I transport it. I thought I might try to do something with these screws, but... how do I unscrew them?

[image] [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be better to ask how you might resolve the problem. Is the issue that they rivet doesn't hold snugly enough? It would be helpful if you'd replace those thumbnail photos will larger ones, but I'd bet you could tighten up the rivets fairly easily.

Comment: @isherwood I wouldn't know if tightening it would do, but that was my first guess. Please see the two new pictures.

Comment: The standard solution to this type of problem is to place a clip or toggle on the underside of the tray that will hold the support to the underside when it is stowed. You really don't want to mess with the rivet. What happens if you carry the tray by holding onto the end and letting gravity hold the support against the bottom of the tray?

Answer (score 3):

That is a rivet. You have to drill rivets out to remove them.